502 Bad Gateway on Azure Ingress for Kubernetes Service /microservice1/hello (Quarkus Application)
I have a Kubernetes cluster running on Azure with an Ingress configured for multiple services. One of these services, microservice1, is a Quarkus application. Locally, the /microservice1/hello endpoint works perfectly. However, when accessing it through the Azure ingress, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.
Other services in the cluster include:
quarkus-service accessible at /qs
react-service accessible at /web
Ingress Configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
  name: simple-frontend-ingress
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.dev.company.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /microservice1/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: microservice1-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /qs
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: quarkus-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /web
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: react-service
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.dev.company.com
      secretName: frontend-tls-prod

Service Configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microservice1-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: microservice1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP

Deployment Configuration:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservice1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: microservice1
          image: myregistry.azurecr.io/microservice1:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: quarkus.http.root-path
              value: /microservice1/

Quarkus application.properties
# Quarkus HTTP Configuration
quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0
quarkus.http.port=8080
quarkus.http.root-path=/microservice1/

# OIDC Configuration
quarkus.oidc.provider=microsoft
quarkus.oidc.client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=YOUR_SECRET
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://example.b2clogin.com/example.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_susi/v2.0/

# Logging Configuration
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".min-level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".level=TRACE

# Microservices
quarkus.rest-client.microservice2.url=${MICROSERVICE2}
quarkus.rest-client.microservice3.url=${MICROSERVICE3}

# Database Configuration
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${DB_URL}
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=20
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=2
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update

EDIT: added dockerfile
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.19

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'


# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 build/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 build/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 build/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 build/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

# Set environment variables in Dockerfile
ENV DB_URL=""
ENV DB_USERNAME=""
ENV DB_PASSWORD=""

EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh" ]

Observations:

Local testing works fine when pointing to http://localhost:8080/microservice1/hello.
The ingress should be correct since i have another quarkus and react application running.
Other services (quarkus-service on /qs and react-service on /web are deployed and are working on the suburl

Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

Your Ingress is configured to forward requests matching /microservice1/ to the service. However, the Quarkus application is configured with quarkus.http.root-path=/microservice1/.
This means the path /microservice1/ is included twice when the request reaches the application: /microservice1/microservice1/hello. Could you please try either this-


path: /microservice1
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: microservice1-service
port:
number: 80


Or adjust the Quarkus quarkus.http.root-path to quarkus.http.root-path=/ and let me know if it helps

i tried the recommended changes but i still get the same error: with path: /microservice1 and quarkus.http.root-path=/ aswell as /microservice1 and the quarkus.http.root-path=/

what i find extra weird is that on my  quarkus-service (/qs) i also have the quarkus.http.root-path=/qs. The application loads normally with /qs aswell as /qs/hello. I just changed the quarku.http.root-path=/ and now the /qs/hello gives a 502 but the /qs/ shows the normal application

the problem was in the backend settings on azure. the custom probe was not set to the specified service
